# Is the MultiRayShape Class working properly?

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am gettting the following error when trying to compile my code: **error: ‘class gazebo::physics::MultiRayShape’ has no member named ‘Ray’**

I am trying to detect which object a laser ray is hitting by following the answer given in http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12982/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-entity-a-ray-or-a-ray-sensor-collides-with/ . Now the API documentation given http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1MultiRayShape.html indicates that this should work. I am using Gazebo version 7.10.0.

After looking through the code for Gazebo, I see that the functions are not implemented, is there some information on when they would implement it or if they have decided to remove the functionality all together? If that is the case, seeing which object has collided with a specific ray is going to be problematic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18509/is-the-multirayshape-class-working-properly?/) by [davidcb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4513/davidcb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After looking through the code for Gazebo 8 and 9, I see that it has been implemented in these versions, so the solution for now is simply to update the Gazebo version and handle the migration problems.

---

Originally posted by [davidcb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4513/davidcb/) with karma: 1 on 2018-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0